# Using "contains (text)" to find parent and following sibling in selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

So I'm trying to build a tool to transfer tickets that I sell. A sale comes into my POS, I do an API call for the section, row, and seat numbers ordered (as well as other information obviously). Using the section, row, and seat number, I want to plug those values into a contains (text) statement to in order to find and select the right tickets on the host site.

Here is a sample of how the tickets are laid out:

[image]

And here is a screenshot (sorry if this is inconvenient) of the DOM related to one of the rows above:

[image]

Given this, how should I structure my contains(text) statement so that it is able to find and select the correct seats? I am very new/inexperienced with automation. I messed around with it a few months ago with some success and have managed to get a tool that gets me right up to selecting the seats but the "div" path confuses me when it comes to searching for text that is tied to other text.

I tried the following structure:

---

```
        for i in range(int(lowseat), int(highseat)):
            web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains (text(), "'+section+'")]/following-sibling::[contains text(), "'+row+'")]/following-sibling::[contains text(), "'+str(i)+'")]').click()
```

---

to no avail. Can someone help me explain how to structure these statements correctly so that it searches for section, row, and seat number correctly?

Thanks!

Also, if needed, here is a screenshot with more context of the button (in cases its needed). Button is highlighted in sky blue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can't use text() for that because it's in nested elements. You probably want to map all these into dicts and select with filter.

**Update**

Here's an idea for a lazy way to do this (untested):

```
button = driver.execute_script('''
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('button')].find(b => {
    return b.innerText.match(/Section 107\b.*Row P.*Seat 10\b/)
  })
''')
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining a little more or pointing me towards a resource? Not sure what "map all these into dicts" means in this context. Very novice level here.